# Adding New Field in customer_address field in Magento

Tags: magento

Okay! I've been researching and doing this customer_module in Magento for 2 weeks now. I already know how to add new field in customer_address but the thing is I want to create that can  run to multiple times. C'oz what I made do 1st run only. If I want to add new field again that old module does not commit any changes at all. Can someone help me please.

Thanks Much!

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend

Answer (score 0):

you need to create upgrade install script. Example You had file in setup folder mysql4-install-1.0.0.php and you setup new attribute for customer. If you want to setup another (new one) attribute : create file with name mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php and change in file config.xml your module version to 1.0.1 ( 1.0.1).